# why eclipse or cmd console caches OS env variables?

Tags: java, caching, environment-variables

I want to get an OS(windows XP) env variable, my code is below(jdk 1.6):

```
public class TestEnv{

public static void main(String...args){
    System.out.println(System.getenv("catalina_home"));
 }
}
```

at frist, there is no variable called `catalina_home` in my PC, it outputs `null`, then I add a `catalina_home` variable in `My Computer > Advanced > Environment Variables`, it still outputs `null`, if I shutdown and restart eclipse, it outputs the correct value. If I run this code in cmd console like this, I shoud close and restart a new cmd console to get correct value, and If I delete an existing variable, first it outputs an non-null value, until I restart eclipse or cmd console, it can outputs `null`. So I think eclipse or cmd console have cached OS env variables, but no proof, even if they really do, I want to know why?
Any idea will be appreciated. Thx very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both on Unix (Linux + Mac) and Windows, processes make a copy of the env variables when they start.

This means the map of variables is always local to a process and it doesn't see changes made by other processes.

There are two reasons:

1. Security. An attacker could modify the behavior of running processes by modifying env variables after the process has started and cause unexpected/unwanted behavior; imagine an attacker could change the `PATH` variable for existing processes. That way, they could inject compromised code into trusted processes.
2. Thread safety. If anyone can change the local variables at any time, you'd need a way to synchronize access and modifications.

Comment: Thread safety is a valid point. Security is IMO a design decision of the OS. After all, modifiction of the environment can just as well be a protected access like reading a directory permission or modifiyng memory pages.

Comment: Note that on the Amiga, env variables are file stores on a special devices `ENV:` (think `/sys/env/varname` on Linux). The filesystem rules govern the access/refresh rules but it allows anyone to change env vars for already running processes at any time. This makes porting software a bit ... odd.

Answer (score 3):

When a process is started it will get a copy of the current environment from it's parent. You have to restart a process in order to get a new set of environment. That's the way it is. :) That is not a problem of eclipse it is how the OS behaves.

Answer (score 0):

If you set an environment variable with the SET command in a command interpreter, it applies right there and then, to that process' environment. No rebooting, no logging off and on — nothing more required.